# Segmentation fault on base class constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, segmentation-fault

Why does it produce a segmentation fault when I create a Rectangle object? I'm thinking that there is something about my constructors that is incorrect but I don't have enough experience in C++ to identify what.

```
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class Shape {
private:
    string name;
    string property_name;
    map<string,double> parameters;


public:
    Shape(){
    }

    void set_name(string n){
        name=n;
    }

    string set_property_name(string s){
        property_name=s;
    }

    void set_parameter(string p, double n){
        parameters[p]=n;
    }

    double get_parameter(string p) {
        return parameters[p];
    }

    virtual double get_property() = 0;

};

class Shape2D: public Shape {
public:
    Shape2D() {
        set_property_name("area");
    }
};

class Rectangle: public Shape2D {
public:
    Rectangle() {
        set_name("rectangle");
        set_parameter("length",0);
        set_parameter("base",0);
    }

    double get_property() {
        return get_parameter("length") *   get_parameter("base");
    }
};


int main() {
  Shape * user_shape;
  user_shape=new Rectangle();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: works fine here. Cannot reproduce. The code seems perfectly fine. Use a debugger to find out what's wrong.

Comment: `set_property_name(string s)` should be of `void` type instead of `string`.Cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre You need a better compiler or higher warnings: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7bee0da403209195

Comment: @NathanOliver I always set warnings to the max on my projects, but when building examples I always do `g++ test.cpp`. It is stupid, I will learn from my errors :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre OK :).  I always turn them up as normally the OP does not and the warning a lot of the times tell you the problem.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'll make an `alias g++="g++ -Wall -Wpedantic -Werror"`. Well, I'll make a `.bat` since I'm running poor windows: aaaaah: `test.cpp: In member function 'std::string Shape::set_property_name(std::string)'. 
:
test.cpp:24:5: error: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Werro
r=return-type]
     }
     ^`. Can we add some rep to the compiler ? :). I know that meta doesn't want it, but a "compile C++ file with g++ all warnings on" button will be a great timesaver for askers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your `string set_property_name(string s)` have no `return` and is undefined behavior

Comment: I couldn't compile without making `set_propert_name(string s)` `void`.How would no return create segFault.

Comment: @GauravSehgal maybe you add some flag and your compiler see *that* as error?

Comment: @GauravSehgal Some compilers will let having no return statement compile as they issue just a warning instead of an error.  In that case when the code reaches the point where it tries to access the return value, but that return value has not been provided then you get a segfault.

Comment: I used visual studio and it won't compile without correcting the return.I was wondering even if the compiler does not warn about this,how would not having a return for a non void function cause seg fault.

Comment: @NathanOliver .Got it.But `set_property_name(string s)` wasn't even called.

Comment: @GauravSehgal Yes it was.  `Shape2D() {set_property_name("area");}`

Comment: @NathanOliver oh yes, got it.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @GauravSehgal No problem.  I would also suggest you test code in a different compiler than MSVS.  [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) is a free, online, g++ and clang compiler that you can use to test code on.  It is nice to have a second opinion on code as compilers can have holes in them.

Comment: @NathanOliver Noted.Thanks again.

Comment: @GauravSehgal: g++ test.cpp (no warning flags) compile (and runs) fine! that's possible to overlook the error if your project options are poor.